# How do I merge a remote repo with my current existing directory?

Tags: python, django, git, unix, bitbucket

I have my Django project in a Bitbucket repo that I want to merge with my newly created Digital Ocean server. The server directory contains a few basic files for a Django project for my server like `env`, `static` and `manage.py`. The Bitbucket repo has all my project apps etc. I've already done `git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git` from the server directory. So I then perform `git merge master` but it says `Already up-to-date.`. I've tried `git pull master` but it says:

```
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any idea what I can try?

Comment: Step 1: avoid `git pull`, it's a bad tool. Step 2: read up on `git fetch` and try `git fetch origin`. Step 3: read up on `git merge` and consider whether you want `git merge origin/master`, or some other command (not merge at all?) or some other thing to merge (not `origin/master` perhaps). All `git pull` does is make you do steps 2 and 3 together, which makes it too hard and painful.

Answer (score 0):

The [`git pull`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) command is used like

```
git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

That means, that you if you are not using any `[options]` you use

```
git pull <repository>
```

which in your case would end up being

```
git pull origin
```

If you want to specify the [`branch`](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) then you can do it like this (for `master`)

```
git pull origin master
```

The command you used (`git pull master`) will not work, because you are telling git to pull from the repository *master*, which does not exist in your [remotes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote). You can already tell my the error message `'master' does not appear to be a git repository`.

If you want to get the changes and merge yourself you can use the [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) command, which is being used my pull anyways.